# Get names of subdirectories (Windows CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How may I list the subdirectories within a folder and store their names in a temporary variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for level 1 directories:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "direcotries="
for /d %%a in (*) do (
  set "direcotries=!direcotries!;%%a"
)
echo %direcotries%
```

for recursive search:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "direcotries="
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
  set "direcotries=!direcotries!;%%a"
)
echo %direcotries%
```

Comment: You might want to correct the spelling of "direcotries" :)

Comment: @DavidPostill - as long as it's consistent, it doesn't really matter :)